# Passing template reference from another element gives undefined with ngIf

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to validate a couple of values on each key stroke, by defining template references for each of the inputs and passing it to a validator function. For some reason however, the ref that's not from the calling input always gives back 'undefined'.

It looks something like this:

Template:

```
<input type="text" *ngIf="oneCondition" placeholder="Key" (keyup)="validateInput(keyElement, valueElement)" #keyElement />
<input type="text" *ngIf="oneCondition" placeholder="Value" #valueElement />
```

Script:

```
public validateInput(key, value): boolean {
        console.log('row', key, value);
}
```

The result is:

> row <input _ngcontent-xxt-c5 placeholder=​"Key" type=​"text" class=​"ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-reflect-model=​"t">​ undefined

The same happens if I put the `(keyup)` on the second element, in which case the first comes out as undefined. I tried to create ViewChildren for these elements just in case, but it didn't work either (and probably isn't relevant).

However, without the condition (ngIf), it seems to work. Why is this, and can this issue be eliminated?

Comment: I think the problem is caused by something else. I've put a Stackblitz demo, as you can see it gets 2 elements reference just fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-opi2i5

Comment: @Xinan thanks you are correct, maybe I just simplified the problem too much. I have edited the question to reflect the change. I guess without ngIf it works, but when adding ngIf (note: it's the same condition), something breaks. Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, `#valueElement` and `#keyElement` are not available outside the elements where `*ngIf` is applied. To overcome this situation, you need to surround your inputs with `<ng-template>` and apply your `*ngIf` to the template. 
Then inside the template, use your input elements.

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="oneCondition">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Key" (keyup)="validateInput(keyElement, valueElement)" #keyElement />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Value" #valueElement />
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to do this if the inputs are not siblings / in the same location?

Comment: You can use ViewChild to access any DOM element

Comment: Yes, but the validator has a different responsibility and isn't supposed to use those variables. I can add a wrapper as a workaround, but it would be nice to know whether it's possible to do this just on the template side. If it's not possible, that's fine as well :)

Comment: If validating multiple fields is your idea, then you can use either **Template-driven validation** or **Reactive form validation**. Refer the documentation at https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: @Ynhockey Also, the answer for your question would be no it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

Now that the problem is clearer I think I can provide a suggestion that I think sufficient to handle this issue.

As you've already known after adding `ngIf` and the condition is false, the element template reference won't be available, which is perfectly expected. Because `ngIf` removes the whole element completely.

Instead of finding a workaround to make element reference still available when `ngIf` is false. I would suggest reconsidering why you need the reference still when the element is removed from the UI? Because that doesn't seem to make sense logically.

A better approach would be to check the availability of the reference and do your logic code accordingly.

```
public validateInput(key, value): boolean {
  if (!value) {
    console.log('value input is not available, condition false, do something else');
  } else {
    console.log('value input is available, process input fields', key, value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not my case. In my case, the ngIf always evaluates to true when the validate function is called. Moreover, while I can perform the check you are suggesting, it doesn't make sense in my case—the validator is called many times, not just as a result of the keyup event and not just for these inputs. The idea is that when it's called, the values should always exist. Basically what Angela suggested is what I'm looking for, but would like to clarify some things there as well.